# How is $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}=2 $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm actually studying the convergence of a series right now. My textbook has an example, but I don't understand the last part of it:
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}=2 $$

If I try by simplifying it:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2^n-1)*2^{1-n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2^n-1)*2^1*2^{-n}  $$

After that, nothing really works and I can't get to 2.
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (2^{n} - 1) \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot 2^{1} = 2^{1} \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - 2^{-n}) = 2^{1} \cdot 1$$

Comment: I don't understand why people provide a pretty much complete answer in the comments @Mattos

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Clearly, only _one more step_ of algebra was needed to get from the OPs answer to the actual answer. So in this case, there wasn't much I could do except give a complete answer now could I? And, to be honest, I don't know why people feel the need to comment on the help others have given, especially when what they say isn't constructive.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question isn't poor quality.

Comment: @jaska I don't understand either. I think this is a fine question

Comment: @ZacharySelk, this is off topic for the current question, and I'll delete it after a few minutes, but I have some questions for you regarding SPDEs and wanted to know how to contact to ask you in private. MSE chat room, Skype, etc?

Comment: @jaska You can always ask questions on here, or ask me through chat if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}&=\frac{2^n}{2^{n-1}}-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\\
&=2-\frac1{2^{n-1}}
\end{align*}
now, take the limit as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{2^{n-1}}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=2-0=2$$

Comment: Would it be better to leave out the "lim" in your penultimate expression?

Comment: Also, you can use `\to` for $\to$ instead of `->`.

Comment: @probablyme thanks

Comment: @GTonyJacobs now fix the answer most clear, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Split up the fraction
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n}{2^{n-1}} -\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n}{2^n2^{-1}} -\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{-1}} -\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{2^{-1}}-0=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is not "seeing" the limit before you verify it. The $1$ on top is crazy small compared to the exponentially growing $2^n.$ What if you just ignored it? You would get $2^n/2^{n-1} = 2.$ That's how you "see" it. That's not a proof, but it tells you what to expect, and that's a great start.